# Image to be in the middle of 2 divs

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs, div 1 & 2. I want to have an image in the middle of the 2 divs (as shown in the image). How do I go about doing so?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You would want to utilize a wrap around the two divs and then absolutely position the image inside the wrap as follows.

```css
html,
body {
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
}
.wrap {
 height: 100%;
}
.image {
 display: block;
 left: 50%;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 position: absolute;
}
.div1, .div2 {
 width: 100%;
 height: 50%;
 float: left;
}
.div1 {
 background: red;
}
.div2 {
 background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
 <img src="https://i.imgur.com/NS73UoB.png" alt="Asshat" height="200" class="image">
 <div class="div1"></div>
 <div class="div2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`#container` is just used to be able to position the elements.
`#picture` should be replaced by your picture
the "magix" is in position absolute and left and top that will place this picture where you want. 50%-50px will center it. -50px in order to compensate for the image size.

```css
#container {
position: relative;
}

#one, #two {
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
background: red;
}

#two {
background: blue;
}

#picture {
background: green;
position: absolute;
left: calc(50% - 50px);
top: calc(50% - 50px);
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div id="one">
</div>
<div id="two">
</div>
<div id="picture">
</div>
</div>
```